# How to get an image from a binary type database using entity framework

Tags: sql, c

I'm trying to get an image from the database, saved in a column with the type varbinary(max), using entity framework.

> Screenshots [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLsg1.png) [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EEYn.png) [Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmstG.png)

I don't understand how to convert the selected object so that the query works correctly I hope it's not a huge code that I can parse, well, or just hints. maybe the request should be written in a different way. thank you in advance

Comment: What datatype is Photo in the user class? `u.Photo` What does the compilation error tell you is wrong?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type "object" to "byte[]". There is an explicit conversion (type casting may have been omitted).

Comment: Change the datatype in the user class to byte[]. Or if that is not possible, try a cast.

Comment: so there is such a type, but it is from the database that the object comes, and the database is stored as binary, but I can't figure out how to convert, accept and use this object.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.